# incompatible mcexam and comment packages?

Tags: errors, packages, incompatibility, comments, mcexam

I need a help in the following code> I don't know what is the issue exactly !!

```
   \documentclass[twoside]{article}
    \usepackage[english]{babel}
    \usepackage{comment}
    % set fonts
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{mathpazo}
    \usepackage{microtype}
    \usepackage{etoolbox}

    \ifdef{\myoutput}{}{\def\myoutput{concept}}
    \ifdef{\myversion}{}{\def\myversion{1}}

    % mcexams options.
    \usepackage[output=exam%\myoutput
    ,numberofversions=2
    ,version=\myversion
    ,seed=1
    ,randomizequestions=true
    ,randomizeanswers=true
    ,writeRfile=true
    ]{mcexam}

    \usepackage[margin=0.95in]{geometry}
    % Packages used for special things
    \usepackage{framed,booktabs} 

    % Set headers and footers
    \usepackage{fancyhdr,lastpage}
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \fancyhf{}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} 
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}
    \lfoot{\mctheversion}
    \rfoot{Page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}

    % Ensure each question+answers is printed entirely on the same page.
    \usepackage{calc}
    \renewenvironment{setmcquestion}{\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth-\labelwidth}}{\end{minipage}\par}

    % question intros should also be printed on the same page.
    \renewenvironment{setmcquestioninstruction}
    {\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}}
        {\end{minipage}}

    \usepackage{multicol}

    % disable paragraph indenting
    \setlength{\parindent}{0cm} % Default is 15pt.

    % no extra space between sentences
    \frenchspacing

    % fix test spacing wonkiness due to grouped questions
    \raggedbottom

    % less space for true/false questions
    \renewenvironment{setmcanswers}{}{}
    \setlist[setmcquestions]{label=\mcquestionlabelfmt{*}.
        ,ref=\mcquestionlabelfmt{*}
        ,itemsep=0.5\baselineskip   
        ,topsep=1\baselineskip
    }

    % use Version 1, 2 etc instead of I, II
    \renewcommand\mcversionlabelfmt[1]{\arabic{#1}}

    \usepackage{array}

    \usepackage{xparse}
    % Rotation macro
    % Rotation: \rot[<angle>][<width>]{<stuff>}
    \NewDocumentCommand{\rot}{O{45} O{1em} m}{\makebox[#2][l]{\rotatebox{#1}{#3}}}%


    % macro for true/false correct answers
    \global\def\qtrue{\begin{mcanswers}[permutenone]\answer[correct]{1}{}\answer{2}{}\end{mcanswers}}
    \global\def\qfalse{\begin{mcanswers}[permutenone]\answer{1}{}\answer[correct]{2}{}\end{mcanswers}}

    % macro for question intros that list the number of questions
    \global\def\numq[#1]{[Questions \the\numexpr\value{setmcquestionsi}+1\relax--\the\numexpr\value{setmcquestionsi}+#1\relax]}

    \global\def\numqq[#1]{(\the\numexpr\value{setmcquestionsi}+#1\relax)}
    \newcommand{\blank}{...............}

    \usepackage{graphicx}

    % ensure always one blank page at end
    \mcifoutput{exam}{
        \AtEndDocument{\ifodd\value{page}
            \newpage\thispagestyle{empty}\hbox{\hfill{}This page intentionally left blank.\hfill{}}\newpage\thispagestyle{empty}\hbox{}
            \else
            \newpage\thispagestyle{empty}\hbox{}
            \fi}
    }

    % custom hyphenation
    \hyphenation{al-kap-to-nu-ri-a}


    \begin{document}

        \begin{comment}
        jkjk
        \end{comment}
        % Exam preamble stuff - this will be printed on every version
        \begin{center}
            \bfseries\Huge My Favorite Exam \\
            \LARGE 
            \today
        \end{center}

        % Show which version is being printed (Concept, Answers, etc.)
        \begin{center}\bfseries\Huge\MakeUppercase{\mctheversion}\end{center}

        % This only shows on the "Exam" form that students see. So put instructions, etc. here.
        \mcifoutput{exam}{
            \large\bigskip

            \noindent Name: \hrulefill{}\hrulefill{}\hrulefill{}\quad{}Student ID\#: \hrulefill\hrulefill{} \\[.75\baselineskip]

            \vfill

            \begin{framed} \centering\bfseries\Large No calculators allowed!  \end{framed}

            \vfill

            On your scantron, use a \#2 pencil to:

            \begin{enumerate}
                \item \textbf{Write and bubble your last name, first name, and student ID\#}
                \item \textbf{Write and bubble your exam version}
            \end{enumerate}

            % ensure that questions don't get printed on this intro page, which annoys students
            \cleardoublepage
            \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.05}
            \normalsize
        } % end if exam


        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        % BEGIN EXAM QUESTIONS %
        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

        \begin{mcquestions}
            \begin{mcquestioninstruction}
                \numq[6] Decide if these sentences are True or False. Mark \textbf{A} for \textbf{True} and \textbf{B} for \textbf{False}.
            \end{mcquestioninstruction}
            \question The details detected by a scanner are not determined by its resolution. \qfalse
            \question [follow] A barcode scanner is a computer peripheral for reading barcode labels printed on products.\qtrue
            \question [follow] Scanners cannot handle optical character recognition. \qfalse
            \question [follow] A digital camera uses a light sensitive film instead of a memory card for storing the images.\qfalse
            \question [follow] A digital video (DV) camera is used to take still photographs.\qfalse
            \question [follow] Video editing software allows you to manipulate video clips on the computer\qtrue



            %%%%%%%%%%
        \end{mcquestions}
    \begin{comment}
     bla bla bla
    \end{comment}
    \end{document}
```

However, after addingone more question, it can be complied without any error. But I don't need the following code. What should I do?

```
\begin{mcquestioninstruction}
    \numq[6] Fill in the blanks with appropriate words given in options.\\
    Having \numqq[1]\blank with friends and family has never been easier or more enjoyable. You get the highest-quality audio and video, no matter
    which chatting solution you use. With the WebCam
    Live! Ultra, its CCD image sensor with 640 x 480
    (VGA) resolution produces rich, vibrant colours.
    Combined with its \numqq[2]\blank 2.0 Hi-Speed connection, the result is top-quality, full-motion video at 30 \numqq[3]\blank per second for all your web conversations, even in dimly-lit rooms. The WebCam Live! Ultra lets you do more. Let your voice be heard clearer than ever before with the included \numqq[4] \blank unlike the built-in microphones in most other \numqq[5]\blank Take still picture at up to 1.3 \numqq[6] \blank resolution (interpolated) and enjoy the many great features that accompany the bundled award-winning WebCam Center software, such as motion detection, remote security monitoring, time-lapse video capture and much more.
\end{mcquestioninstruction}
%1
\question
\begin{multicols}{4}
    \begin{mcanswerslist}[ordinal]
        \answer webcams
        \answer headset
        \answer[correct] \mbox{video~conferences}
        \answer frames
    \end{mcanswerslist}
\end{multicols}
%2
```

My second question is about compability of comment and mcexam package. When I try to add a commend argument before the \end{mcquestions}, it shows me an error, however if I put comment argument after \end{mcquestions}, it can be compiled correctly ! 
Log(first line):

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99999 (TeX Live 2018/W32TeX) (preloaded format=xelatex 2018.7.17)  24 DEC 2018 17:38
```

I hope someone can help me to find a workaround to solve this problem.
Thanks
Update:
Error log from log file:

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99999 (TeX Live 2018/W32TeX) (preloaded format=xelatex 2018.7.17)  29 DEC 2018 10:31
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**main.tex
(./main.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-04-01> patch level 2
Babel <3.18> and hyphenation patterns for 84 language(s) loaded.
(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count80
\c@section=\count81
\c@subsection=\count82
\c@subsubsection=\count83
\c@paragraph=\count84
\c@subparagraph=\count85
\c@figure=\count86
\c@table=\count87
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty
Package: babel 2018/02/14 3.18 The Babel package

(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/switch.def
File: switch.def 2018/02/14 3.18 Babel switching mechanism
)
(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-english/english.ldf
Language: english 2017/06/06 v3.3r English support from the babel system

(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.def
File: babel.def 2018/02/14 3.18 Babel common definitions
\babel@savecnt=\count88
\U@D=\dimen103

(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/xebabel.def
(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/txtbabel.def))
\bbl@dirlevel=\count89
)
\l@canadian = a dialect from \language\l@american 
\l@australian = a dialect from \language\l@british 
\l@newzealand = a dialect from \language\l@british 
))
(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/comment/comment.sty
\CommentStream=\write3

Excluding comment 'comment')
(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty
Package: inputenc 2018/04/06 v1.3b Input encoding file
\inpenc@prehook=\toks14
\inpenc@posthook=\toks15


Package inputenc Warning: inputenc package ignored with utf8 based engines.

) (c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
Package: fontenc 2017/04/05 v2.0i Standard LaTeX package

(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.def
File: t1enc.def 2017/04/05 v2.0i Standard LaTeX file
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding T1 on input line 48.
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for T1+lmr on input line 105.

(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lm/t1lmr.fd
File: t1lmr.fd 2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
))
(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/mathpazo.sty
Package: mathpazo 2005/04/12 PSNFSS-v9.2a Palatino w/ Pazo Math (D.Puga, WaS) 
\symupright=\mathgroup4
)
(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/microtype.sty
Package: microtype 2018/01/14 v2.7a Micro-typographical refinements (RS)

(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks16
)
\MT@toks=\toks17
\MT@count=\count90
LaTeX Info: Redefining \textls on input line 793.
\MT@outer@kern=\dimen104
LaTeX Info: Redefining \textmicrotypecontext on input line 1339.
\MT@listname@count=\count91

(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/microtype-xetex.def
File: microtype-xetex.def 2018/01/14 v2.7a Definitions specific to xetex (RS)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \lsstyle on input line 256.
)
Package microtype Info: Loading configuration file microtype.cfg.

(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/microtype.cfg
File: microtype.cfg 2018/01/14 v2.7a microtype main configuration file (RS)
))
(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty
Package: etoolbox 2018/02/11 v2.5e e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
\etb@tempcnta=\count92
) (./mcexam.sty
(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
Package: xkeyval 2014/12/03 v2.7a package option processing (HA)

(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex
\XKV@toks=\toks18
\XKV@tempa@toks=\toks19
)
\XKV@depth=\count93
File: xkeyval.tex 2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
))
(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/environ/environ.sty
Package: environ 2014/05/04 v0.3 A new way to define environments

(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/trimspaces/trimspaces.sty
Package: trimspaces 2009/09/17 v1.1 Trim spaces around a token list
)
\@envbody=\toks20
)
(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/newfile/newfile.sty
Package: newfile 2009/09/03 v1.0c Output and input files

(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/verbatim.sty
Package: verbatim 2014/10/28 v1.5q LaTeX2e package for verbatim enhancements
\every@verbatim=\toks21
\verbatim@line=\toks22
\verbatim@in@stream=\read1
)
\c@streamvline=\count94
)
(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/enumitem/enumitem.sty
Package: enumitem 2011/09/28 v3.5.2 Customized lists
\labelindent=\skip43
\enit@outerparindent=\dimen105
\enit@toks=\toks23
\enit@inbox=\box26
\enitdp@description=\count95
)
(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/longtable.sty
Package: longtable 2014/10/28 v4.11 Multi-page Table package (DPC)
\LTleft=\skip44
\LTright=\skip45
\LTpre=\skip46
\LTpost=\skip47
\LTchunksize=\count96
\LTcapwidth=\dimen106
\LT@head=\box27
\LT@firsthead=\box28
\LT@foot=\box29
\LT@lastfoot=\box30
\LT@cols=\count97
\LT@rows=\count98
\c@LT@tables=\count99
\c@LT@chunks=\count100
\LT@p@ftn=\toks24
)
(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgffor.sty
(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.sty
(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.tex
\pgfutil@everybye=\toks25
\pgfutil@tempdima=\dimen107
\pgfutil@tempdimb=\dimen108

(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common-lists.tex)
) (c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-latex.def
\pgfutil@abb=\box31

(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ms/everyshi.sty
Package: everyshi 2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
))
(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.code.tex
Package: pgfrcs 2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.31)
))
(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.sty
(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex
\pgfkeys@pathtoks=\toks26
\pgfkeys@temptoks=\toks27

(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeysfiltered.code.tex
\pgfkeys@tmptoks=\toks28
))) (c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/math/pgfmath.sty
(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathutil.code.tex
\pgf@x=\dimen109
\pgf@xa=\dimen110
\pgf@xb=\dimen111
\pgf@xc=\dimen112
\pgf@y=\dimen113
\pgf@ya=\dimen114
\pgf@yb=\dimen115
\pgf@yc=\dimen116
\c@pgf@counta=\count101
\c@pgf@countb=\count102
\c@pgf@countc=\count103
\c@pgf@countd=\count104
)
(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex
\pgfmath@dimen=\dimen117
\pgfmath@count=\count105
\pgfmath@box=\box32
\pgfmath@toks=\toks29
\pgfmath@stack@operand=\toks30
\pgfmath@stack@operation=\toks31
)
(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.basic.code.te
x)
(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.trigonometric
.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.random.code.t
ex)
(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.comparison.co
de.tex)
(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.base.code.tex
)
(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.round.code.te
x)
(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.misc.code.tex
)
(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.integerarithm
etics.code.tex)))
(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfloat.code.tex
\c@pgfmathroundto@lastzeros=\count106
)))
(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgffor.code.tex
Package: pgffor 2013/12/13 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.25)

(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex)
\pgffor@iter=\dimen118
\pgffor@skip=\dimen119
\pgffor@stack=\toks32
\pgffor@toks=\toks33
))
(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xstring/xstring.sty
(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xstring/xstring.tex
\@xs@message=\write4
\integerpart=\count107
\decimalpart=\count108
)
Package: xstring 2013/10/13  v1.7c  String manipulations (C Tellechea)
)
Package: mcexam 2017/12/26 v0.4 LaTeX package for creating randomized Multiple 
Choice questions
\c@mcversion=\count109
\c@mc@counter=\count110
\c@mc@mcquestions=\count111
\mc@qbox=\box33
\mc@abox=\box34
\c@setmcquestionsi=\count112
\enitdp@setmcquestions=\count113
\c@setmcanswerslisti=\count114
\enitdp@setmcanswerslist=\count115
\enitdp@setmcquestioninfo=\count116
\@Rfileoutstre@m=\write5
)
(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty
Package: geometry 2018/03/24 v5.7 Page Geometry

(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty
Package: ifpdf 2017/03/15 v3.2 Provides the ifpdf switch
)
(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifvtex.sty
Package: ifvtex 2016/05/16 v1.6 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
Package ifvtex Info: VTeX not detected.
)
(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty
Package: ifxetex 2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
)
\Gm@cnth=\count117
\Gm@cntv=\count118
\c@Gm@tempcnt=\count119
\Gm@bindingoffset=\dimen120
\Gm@wd@mp=\dimen121
\Gm@odd@mp=\dimen122
\Gm@even@mp=\dimen123
\Gm@layoutwidth=\dimen124
\Gm@layoutheight=\dimen125
\Gm@layouthoffset=\dimen126
\Gm@layoutvoffset=\dimen127
\Gm@dimlist=\toks34
)
(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/framed/framed.sty
Package: framed 2011/10/22 v 0.96: framed or shaded text with page breaks
\OuterFrameSep=\skip48
\fb@frw=\dimen128
\fb@frh=\dimen129
\FrameRule=\dimen130
\FrameSep=\dimen131
)
(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/booktabs/booktabs.sty
Package: booktabs 2016/04/27 v1.618033 publication quality tables
\heavyrulewidth=\dimen132
\lightrulewidth=\dimen133
\cmidrulewidth=\dimen134
\belowrulesep=\dimen135
\belowbottomsep=\dimen136
\aboverulesep=\dimen137
\abovetopsep=\dimen138
\cmidrulesep=\dimen139
\cmidrulekern=\dimen140
\defaultaddspace=\dimen141
\@cmidla=\count120
\@cmidlb=\count121
\@aboverulesep=\dimen142
\@belowrulesep=\dimen143
\@thisruleclass=\count122
\@lastruleclass=\count123
\@thisrulewidth=\dimen144
)
(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.sty
Package: fancyhdr 2017/06/30 v3.9a Extensive control of page headers and footer
s
\f@nch@headwidth=\skip49
\f@nch@O@elh=\skip50
\f@nch@O@erh=\skip51
\f@nch@O@olh=\skip52
\f@nch@O@orh=\skip53
\f@nch@O@elf=\skip54
\f@nch@O@erf=\skip55
\f@nch@O@olf=\skip56
\f@nch@O@orf=\skip57
)
(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lastpage/lastpage.sty
Package: lastpage 2015/03/29 v1.2m Refers to last page's name (HMM; JPG)
)
(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/calc.sty
Package: calc 2017/05/25 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
\calc@Acount=\count124
\calc@Bcount=\count125
\calc@Adimen=\dimen145
\calc@Bdimen=\dimen146
\calc@Askip=\skip58
\calc@Bskip=\skip59
LaTeX Info: Redefining \setlength on input line 80.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \addtolength on input line 81.
\calc@Ccount=\count126
\calc@Cskip=\skip60
)
(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/multicol.sty
Package: multicol 2018/04/01 v1.8r multicolumn formatting (FMi)
\c@tracingmulticols=\count127
\mult@box=\box35
\multicol@leftmargin=\dimen147
\c@unbalance=\count128
\c@collectmore=\count129
\doublecol@number=\count130
\multicoltolerance=\count131
\multicolpretolerance=\count132
\full@width=\dimen148
\page@free=\dimen149
\premulticols=\dimen150
\postmulticols=\dimen151
\multicolsep=\skip61
\multicolbaselineskip=\skip62
\partial@page=\box36
\last@line=\box37
\maxbalancingoverflow=\dimen152
\mult@rightbox=\box38
\mult@grightbox=\box39
\mult@gfirstbox=\box40
\mult@firstbox=\box41
\@tempa=\box42
\@tempa=\box43
\@tempa=\box44
\@tempa=\box45
\@tempa=\box46
\@tempa=\box47
\@tempa=\box48
\@tempa=\box49
\@tempa=\box50
\@tempa=\box51
\@tempa=\box52
\@tempa=\box53
\@tempa=\box54
\@tempa=\box55
\@tempa=\box56
\@tempa=\box57
\@tempa=\box58
\c@columnbadness=\count133
\c@finalcolumnbadness=\count134
\last@try=\dimen153
\multicolovershoot=\dimen154
\multicolundershoot=\dimen155
\mult@nat@firstbox=\box59
\colbreak@box=\box60
\mc@col@check@num=\count135
)
(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/array.sty
Package: array 2018/04/07 v2.4g Tabular extension package (FMi)
\col@sep=\dimen156
\ar@mcellbox=\box61
\extrarowheight=\dimen157
\NC@list=\toks35
\extratabsurround=\skip63
\backup@length=\skip64
\ar@cellbox=\box62
)
(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty
(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
Package: expl3 2018/03/05 L3 programming layer (loader) 


(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 2017/06/01 v1.1a Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2017/06/25 v1.2c Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty
Package: trig 2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: xetex.def on input line 99.


(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/t1ppl.fd
File: t1ppl.fd 2001/06/04 font definitions for T1/ppl.
)
\big@size=\dimen191
LaTeX Info: Redefining \microtypecontext on input line 101.
Package microtype Info: Character protrusion enabled (level 2).
Package microtype Info: Using default protrusion set `alltext'.
Package microtype Info: No adjustment of tracking.
Package microtype Info: No adjustment of spacing.
Package microtype Info: No adjustment of kerning.

(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/mt-ppl.cfg
File: mt-ppl.cfg 2005/11/16 v1.6 microtype config. file: Palatino (RS)
)
ABD: EveryShipout initializing macros
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: xetex
*geometry* verbose mode - [ preamble ] result:
* driver: xetex
* paper: <default>
* layout: <same size as paper>
* layoutoffset:(h,v)=(0.0pt,0.0pt)
* modes: twoside 
* h-part:(L,W,R)=(68.65627pt, 476.98247pt, 68.65627pt)
* v-part:(T,H,B)=(68.65627pt, 657.65746pt, 68.65627pt)
* \paperwidth=614.295pt
* \paperheight=794.96999pt
* \textwidth=476.98247pt
* \textheight=657.65746pt
* \oddsidemargin=-3.61372pt
* \evensidemargin=-3.61372pt
* \topmargin=-40.61372pt
* \headheight=12.0pt
* \headsep=25.0pt
* \topskip=10.0pt
* \footskip=30.0pt
* \marginparwidth=121.0pt
* \marginparsep=11.0pt
* \columnsep=10.0pt
* \skip\footins=9.0pt plus 4.0pt minus 2.0pt
* \hoffset=0.0pt
* \voffset=0.0pt
* \mag=1000
* \@twocolumnfalse
* \@twosidetrue
* \@mparswitchtrue
* \@reversemarginfalse
* (1in=72.27pt=25.4mm, 1cm=28.453pt)

Package lastpage Info: Please have a look at the pageslts package at
(lastpage)             https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pageslts
(lastpage)             ! on input line 101.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `T1/ppl/bx/n' in size <10> not available
(Font)              Font shape `T1/ppl/b/n' tried instead on input line 108.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `T1/ppl/bx/n' in size <24.88> not available
(Font)              Font shape `T1/ppl/b/n' tried instead on input line 108.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `T1/ppl/bx/n' in size <17.28> not available
(Font)              Font shape `T1/ppl/b/n' tried instead on input line 109.

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 139--139

 []

LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `T1/ppl/bx/n' in size <12> not available
(Font)              Font shape `T1/ppl/b/n' tried instead on input line 139.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `T1/ppl/bx/n' in size <14.4> not available
(Font)              Font shape `T1/ppl/b/n' tried instead on input line 139.
[1

] [2

]

! LaTeX Error: \begin{document} ended by \end{mcquestions}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.160         \end{mcquestions}

Your command was ignored.
Type  I <command> <return>  to replace it with another command,
or  <return>  to continue without it.

! Extra \endgroup.
<recently read> \endgroup 

l.160         \end{mcquestions}

Things are pretty mixed up, but I think the worst is over.


AED: lastpage setting LastPage
[3

] [4] (./main.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 18496 strings out of 492970
 356078 string characters out of 6137298
 440765 words of memory out of 5000000
 22327 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 539332 words of font info for 31 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1349 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 47i,10n,68p,10438b,233s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s

Output written on main.pdf (4 pages).
```

Comment: Please post the log from the system, not from your editor editors may often filter away relevant stuff.

Comment: what do you mean from my system ? how can I do it ?

Comment: This is the error I get : Argument of \verbatim@ has an extra }.

Comment: Is this issue solved? How?